# SET PGPASSWORD with asterisk character not working

Tags: windows, postgresql, batch-file, psql

I use a batch file to copy data from a database to other like this:

```
SET PGPASSWORD=passtest

"C:\Program Files\e-SUS\database\postgresql-9.6.13-4-windows-x64\bin\psql.exe" -h 10.10.10.10 -p 5433 -d esus -U postgres -c "\copy (SELECT * from mytable) to 'e:\data.csv' with csv header"

IF EXIST e:\data.csv ( "C:\Program Files\e-SUS\database\postgresql-9.6.13-4-windows-x64\bin\psql.exe" -h 11.11.11.11 -p 5433 -d esus -U postgres -c "\copy mytable from 'e:\data.csv' with csv header delimiter ','" )
```

this works correctly, but if my password have a asterisk character like `SET PGPASSWORD=pass*test` this not works... I try to use `SET PGPASSWORD=pass%*test` but this not works too.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the asterisk:

```sh
SET PGPASSWORD="sec*ret"
```

Comment: Since `PGPASSORD` does not appear in the posted code, it would appear that it is being read from the environment. Although your response is likely to work (I have no way of testing other than simply observing the variable's value), a preferred syntax would be `SET "PGPASSWORD="sec*ret""` where the outer quote-pair delimits the string being assigned and stray trailing spaces are ignored. This is a general principle - probably not relevant here, but if such strays are ignored, it can cause chaos.

Comment: the correctr code is `SET "PGPASSWORD=sec*ret"` edit your code to I aprove your answer

Comment: Please edit it yourself, I have no way of verifying that. I will approve the edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
 set "PGPASSWORD=yourpass"
```